# Send HTTPS request from Event Bridge to Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to hit an API gateway endpoint with a custom domain from event bridge. I was able to create this process with a toy example. However, with the actual implementation there exists a custom domain on the endpoint.

I am getting a 307 status back from api gateway (see response below)

```
{
""statusCode"": 307, 
""headers"": {""content-length"": ""0"", 
              ""location"": ""https://<api-id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/healthCheck""}, 
""multiValueHeaders"": {}, 
""body"": """", 
""isBase64Encoded"": false}"
```

From what I have researched, when sending an HTTP request secure endpoint, AWS will redirect because the HTTP request is disallowed and it wants HTTPS.

How can I hit this secure endpoint with event bridge?

Comment: Can you add more detail, as I can't make head or tails of it at all. What are you trying to achieve? What is the request? Why can't you call the custom domain and why it's a difference?

Comment: I actually don't think this is a problem with the custom domain. I did think it was. I created a toy example and was able to make everything work, but for some reason, the API I am using is different.